# What are the alternatives to PayPal for non-supported countries?

Tags: online-payment, paypal, alternatives

What are the alternatives to PayPal for countries whom PayPal does not support?

For example, I am from Pakistan and I am looking for easy way like PayPal to transfer and receive amounts from the services buyers whom I render my freelance service.

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I found [this page](http://money.cnn.com/galleries/2008/fsb/0802/gallery.paypal_alternatives.fsb/index.html) at CNN Money, that lists 5 viable alternatives to Paypal, namely:

1. Digital River
2. 2checkout.com
3. Alertpay
4. TrialPay
5. E-Junkie

I would suggest looking for unbiased sources like CNN rather than searching for alternatives and happening upon the merchant's sites themselves.

Hope this helps!